# Magento 2 :How to write ategory URL rewrite

Tags: magento2.3.1, seo, redirect-url

How to write 301 redirections to the category page

Category URL key is "**ballasts**"

**request path :** ballasts.html

**target path :** catalog/category/view/id/10

When the user hit this URL directly in the browser http://127.0.0.1/robertson/catalog/category/view/id/10, it should redirect to http://127.0.0.1/robertson/ballasts.html

Can anyone guide me for this 301 redirection

[image]

Comment: Do you want to add it from admin Or using SQL query ? and redirect should be ` http://127.0.0.1/robertson/ballasts.html` Right ?

Comment: via Admin and yes the redirected url is correct

Comment: what happens when you hit `http://127.0.0.1/robertson/catalog/ballasts.html` ? is it working ?

Comment: Please see the updated url above

Comment: I need to redirect it to 127.0.0.1/robertson/ballasts.html

Comment: i think it will be work if just save category from admin! Please save category.

Comment: how do I change it via admin because the target path is uneditable? Please see my attachment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110703/discussion-between-pawan-and-jaisa).